# Show all agendas as tiles in windows taskbar calendar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, calendar

I like the tiled-display which indicates upcoming events in the Windows Calendar app.

[image]

That enables me to quickly glance that at which dates I have an agenda planned.

The Windows taskbar calendar, however, **shows *only* Today's agenda.**

[image]

It doesn't contain ***highlighted tiles* to indicate what other agendas are upcoming.**

**Question:**

> Is there a way to enable this in the Windows Taskbar calendar? Or which additional software do I need to install to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't help more than to say "Can't reproduce it here, without any tricks". This is my **tomorrow agenda** from real calendar (I'm too lazy to perform special test)

[image: Agenta 4 future]

Comment: I think you explicitly _clicked_ on the date 22 to show the agenda. The thing I want is *"highlighted tiles" indicating that an agenda is upcoming*. I hope I'm clear now?